# Nuxt + GraphQL (Apollo) upload files

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo

I am currently using `@nuxt/apollo` module. Does this module work for file uploading or I need to change the HTTPLink to another one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nuxt 2.x with apollo 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69699769/nuxt-2-x-with-apollo-3)

Comment: @kissu, Thanks but as you could see it was my question as well)) so, it didn't even close solve my issue) But anyway thanks for being around!

Answer (score 1):

After a deep check on the libs and my stack, I finally figured out the issue.
I've made very simple setups of both frontend and backend following the recent docs (they have changed dramatically since I worked with them last time) and I figured out that apparently `@nuxt/apollo` supports file upload out of the box (Thanks for that to [Guillaume Chau](https://github.com/Akryum))

The problem was with my backend where I had to update `apollo-server-express` from `"^2.21.0"` to `"^3.4.0"` (I was following the docs but the version I had was older and it didn't support file uploads) and in accordance with the recent docs I already had to use `graphqlUploadExpress` middleware and start the GraphQL server first like this:

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: schema,
    debug: true,
    context: contextHook
})

export const applyGraphQLMiddleware = async ({ server: app }: { server: Application }) => {
    app.use(graphqlUploadExpress()); // adding this middleware
    await apolloServer.start(); // starting the GraphQL Server 
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app }); // only after that I am applying the express server as a middleware
}
```

Now file uploading seems to work as it should

Just in case, you can find the whole setup of Schema and Resolvers in [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/)